# Python - TypeError: Cannot create graphics instruction outside the main Kivy thread

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to change the screen after running this function which is a thread. but it gives me the error

```
 TypeError: Cannot create graphics instruction outside the main Kivy thread
```

I researched online regarding this and they told me to use clock property but I don't know how I can use it here. I just want to be able to change graphic instructions from this command. but if I don't thread it the app goes into not responding.

This is my code:

```py
class Notice(Screen):
    def thread_notice(self):
            t1 = Thread(target= Notice.sendNotice, args =(self,))
            t1.daemon = True
            t1.start()
        
    def sendNotice(self):
        my_big_chunk_of_code()
        kv.current = 'menu'
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do any kivy instructions outside of the main thread, which means you cant run sendNotice on a diffrent thread becuase it has kivy code in it... if `my_big_chunk_of_code()` takes time then remove the `kv.current = 'menu'` line and move it to, for example the thread_notice function.

By the way in the thread I suggest making the target: `self.sendNotice` instead of `Notice.sendNotice` which i think creates another instance of that class (not sure tho), it should work the same

Comment: but if i put `kv.current = menu` in the thread_notice it will change the screen as soon as the thread is started

Comment: Then, instead you can call a function that has `kv.current = menu` inside of it and then call it from the big function. Above the function you added add @mainthread

Answer (score 0):

I am late but well I am posting this answer so that It will help other in future , So Because you can not create graphics instruction outside the main Kivy thread, so you have  to be bit tricky about it, I was facing the same problem while ago, So here is how I solve it, So you should first create a popup before starting a thread and than start your thread and if you want to pass argument in your function inside thread, you should use a lambda function like this.

```
    self.showLoadingPopUp() # showing pop up before starting thread
    try:
    # Using lambda  function for passing arguments in function inside thread
       threading.Thread(target=lambda : self.yourFunction(argument)).start() 
    except:
         print("Error: unable to start thread")
```

This will not block your UI and when you create popup function make sure to use  a class variable for that, So you can able to close that popup from your thread function, here is the exaple -

```
class MyApp(App):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.window = None
        self.loading = None

    # Main Build function
    def build(self):
        self.window = GridLayout()
        self.window.cols = 2
  
        return self.window

    def showLoadingPopUp(self):
        content = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        self.loading = Popup(title="Loading", title_color='#FFFFFF', content=content, size=('700dp', '200dp'),
                             size_hint=(None, None),
                             auto_dismiss=False,
                             background='#FFFFFF')
        content.add_widget(Label(text="Loading...", color="#FFFFFF"))

        def _on_d(*args):
            self.loading.is_visable = False

        self.loading.bind(on_dismiss=_on_d)
        self.loading.is_visable = True

        self.loading.open()

        while not self.loading.is_visable:
            EventLoop.idle()

    def yourFunction(self, argument):
        for i in list:
            # code
        self.loading.dismiss() # dismissing old popup
```

So In short this function will first create a popup and than it will start a thread and when our work is done the thread will just close the popup with class variable in the end. Hope it's help.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it worked importing mainthread from kivy.core then setting the function with this decorator:

like:
`

```
from kivy.clock import mainthread
from kivy.app import App

class MyApp(App):

    @mainthread
    def create_something(self, *args): # this will run in mainthread, even if called  outside.
        # cool things created here
```

`